# Is there any way to extract files from 7z format using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.6, 7zip

I'm trying to extract files from a 7z format using python. Can some tell how it can be done on python 3.6?

Comment: You can use py7zr, which supports 7zip archive compression, decompression, encryption and decryption. https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr/

Answer (score -5):

You can use the following : 
https://pypi.org/project/pyunpack/

Or you can use the following :
from zipfile import ZipFile

```
with ZipFile('your_zip_file.zip') as zipArch: #or a 7z file
    zipArch.extractall("dest_folder", pwd=bytes('the_zip_password','utf-8')) #If it is password protected
```

Comment: Unzipping 7z causes BadZipFile exception

Comment: `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`